# Libgdx Render method

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a question on libgdx render method, I am currently designing a game that requires me to draw different type of images to the screen upon the user request.  However I am having this issue where by the game screen will get blank out after 4-5 tries, I realised the render method is somehow a endless loop. So my question is how does the render method actually works ? need some explanation on that, had checked the documentation for it but dont really understand.

Much help is appreciated, Thanks!!!

leDon

Answer (score 1):

`render` method is responsible for rendering your graphics, and it's called in every frame (30 up to 80 times per second, depending on your hardware).

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsContinuous